# In this snippet how do I force the function to use gravatar rated G and fill in the alt for get_avatar()?

Tags: theme-development, gravatar

```
$title = sprintf( '%1$s<span class="vcard">%2$s</span>',
                get_avatar( get_the_author_meta( 'ID' ), 75, set_url_scheme( 'https'), '', '' ),//TODO Full avatar via gravatar
                get_the_author()
            );
```

The alt might be the `the_author_meta( 'display_name', 'ID' );`?

Comment: Did you read https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_avatar first?

Comment: ofc that is why I came here. I couldn't make sense of it.

Comment: i will search and think about a solution

Comment: @SerkanAlgur any luck?